# Sponsor logo takes over a second to appear and shifts the entire page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, mobile-chrome, sponsored-sites

Sponsor logo takes over a second to appear and shifts the entire page. This messes up one's clicks if the page shifts while clicking. E.g., if often messes up my click on "Ask Question".

That'd be preferable if the sponsorship logo wouldn't shift the page that long after the user visits the page.

Example with AWS:

[image]

Tested on chrome on Android on a Pixel 6.

Comment: This also happens sometimes with adds.

Comment: The resolution would be simple, especially in the case of the logo, which is always there in contrast to adds which show up sporadically. Depending on the browsers width they could set the height of the top bar before the logo is rendered, and thus avoid the jumpy behavior.

Comment: @Luuklag the code is the same for all sites, and not all sites have a sponsor, so they can't put a fixed placeholder. It's dynamic, and the code perform the "load sponsor" after page load. So it's not as simple as one might think.